# Matlab and out of memory error

Tags: matlab, memory

I am working with a sparse tensor of size 5440 * 2538 * 368, which only takes 21 MB of memory. However I am using a ParCube tensor factorization and there it creates a zeros matrix and hence there I get out of memory error. Unfortunately unlike other algorithms, for tensor factorization I cannot break data and work with smaller pieces. I am running this on a Linux server with almost 109GB of free memory. I have read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html), but it seems that it doesn't work either. (I am running 64b Matlab on 64b Linux and I have set the Java Heap Memory to its maximum which is 128941MB).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the zeros matrix defined as a `sparse()` matrix? I assume not, or if it is, is the final result really sparse? In case it is not a `sparse()` matrix require 3 times as much memory per element. It is hard to know what happens exactly without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is a sparse matrix only 0.00013 original matrix has non-zero elements and   looking at the factorization code, it actually needs to be zero and not sparse.

Comment: In that case I assume you need to try using some kind of swap file if this is possible. In case the matrix is not defined as `sparse()` there is no way that this will fit into the RAM at the same time.